# FMS FLV to mp3/aac/wav

Tags: ffmpeg, flash-media-server, codec, fms3

How can I decode a FLV's audio if it's recorded from a live stream using Flash Media Server and uses NellyMoser codec?

I'm writing a script that process several FLVs, using FFmpeg, so I need a command line solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, since NellyMoser is supported by FFmpeg. 

1. Using mp3

```
ffmpeg -i yourinput.flv -vn -acodec libmp3lame output.flv
```

2. Using AAC (switch aac with libfaac depending on which you have loaded)

```
ffmpeg -i yourinput.flv -vn -acodec libfaac output.mp4
```

I'm assuming of course you dont care about video.