# FMS FLV (Speex) to mp3/mp4/acc/wav

Tags: ffmpeg, flv, flash-media-server, speex

I'm trying to decode an FLV's audio to a playable format.  I attempted to use this SO post: [FMS FLV to mp3..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655089/fms-flv-to-mp3-aac-wav) as an example, but my FLV is encoded in Speex.

I have compiled ffmpeg with --enable-libspeex on a Fedora 15 machine.

I believe this can be done with ffmpeg but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

Any thoughts?  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ffmpeg needs to be configured with `--enable-libspeex` to support Speex decoding. Since you did not provide your OS I can not give any more specific instructions. Once you have a build of ffmpeg that can decode speex the most simple command would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv output.wav
```

Answer (score 2):

while reencoding flv file (speex to mp3) if you get sample rate error try this:

```
ffmpeg -i c:\in.flv -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -vcodec copy c:\out.flv
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what your input. As long as you have the decoder and encoder enabled in your ffmpeg it will do it.

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.flv -acodec libmp3lame any_other_parameters_you_want -vcodec copy out.flv
```

will do the trick.

run ffmpeg -codecs to see the codecs supported and ffmpeg -formats to see the formats supported in your install.